# Abstract Definition of $\log$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose $l:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and satisfies

(1) $l(e)=1$ and

(2) $l(xy)=l(x) + l(y)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.

I'd like to show $l=\log$ (the natural logarithm).

I can prove this claim for positive irrationals (once I complete the proof for positive rationals), but I'm having an issue with the positive rationals. I'm also unsure how to use the fact that $l(e)=1$, but I'm sure this fact is needed to obtain an equality containing both $l$ and $\log$.

**What I have:**

$l(x)=l(x\cdot 1)=l(x)+l(1)\Rightarrow l(1)=0$.

Suppose $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then $0=l(1)=l(n/n)=l(n)+l(1/n)\Rightarrow l(1/n)=-l(n).$  Therefore,  $l(m/n)=l(m) - l(n) $. These are all desirable equalities, but how do I obtain an equality that introduces $\log$?

Comment: You haven't used continuity yet. The irrationals can be approximated by a sequence of rationals.

Comment: Try to consider function $f(x)=l(e^x)$. It is easy to see that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, so $f$ is linear function ($f(x)=cx$ for some $c$).

Comment: @InTransit, I know that the irrationals can be approximated by irrationals, that's why I don't need help with proving $l=\log$ for irrationals, only rationals.

Comment: @AustinMohr no the OP has shown that $f(0) = 0$, check the definition of $f$ that user121270 gave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of positive rationals use rational powers of $e$ to approximate other numbers. After all, $l(e^{\frac{m}{n}}) = \frac{m}{n} = \log(e^{\frac{m}{n}})$. The continuity of $e$ implies that $y=\inf\{e^{\frac{m}{n}}|m,n\in\mathbb Z, n>0, e^{\frac{m}{n}}\leq y\}$ for each $y\in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: How do we know that $l(e^{\frac{m}{n}})=\frac{m}{n}$?

Comment: This way: $n*l(e^{\frac{m}{n}}) = l(e^m) = m$ by rule (2).